# Basis for the space of Harmonic homogeneous polynomial in N variables.

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Hello,

Does someone know an explicit basis of the space of harmonic homogeneous polynomial in N variables.

When $N=3$, if I'm not mistaking Legendre polynomial allow to write an explicit basis.

Is there a known explicit basis when $N > 3$ ?

Thanks for your answers, and reference in case you know one.

Comment: I really want a basis for harmonic homogeneous polynomials, by harmonic I mean in the kernel of the euclidean laplacian.

And, such a polynomial restrict to the sphere give a eigenvector for the spherical laplacian, right ?

But, I don't get your "If the former, apply the laplacian on monomials to see what happens and why I think that you may not really want to know about harmonic homogeneous polynomials."

Do you mean that such a basis will be awfully too complicated ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question.  My comment does not apply and I will delete it.  Sorry.



Comment: The Gegenbauer Polynomials are the generalization of associated Legendre Polynomials to higher dimensions: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GegenbauerPolynomial.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $K$ denote the [Kelvin transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_transform), and let $|\alpha|:=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j$ denote the weight of the multi-index $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^n$. Then, an explicit base for the space of homogeneous harmonic polynomials   in $n$ variables and degreee $m$, $\mathcal H^m:=\mathcal H^m[x_1,\dots ,x_n]$,  is
$$\big\{ K\big(\partial^\alpha\|x\|^{2-n}\big) : |\alpha|=m, \alpha_n\leq 1 \big\}.$$
Indeed, an easy combinatorial computation shows it has the right cardinality $$\operatorname{card}\{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^n  : |\alpha|=m, \alpha_n\leq 1 \}=
{n+m-1\choose n-1} - {n+m-3\choose n-1} = \operatorname{dim}\mathcal H^m,$$ 
(the latter dimension being already known from linear algebra considerations on the operator $\Delta$). On the other hand, one can verify that it spans the same linear space as the analogous set without the constraint on $\alpha_n$:
$$\{ K\big(\partial^\alpha\|x\|^{2-n}\big): |\alpha|=m\},$$
which is the whole space $\mathcal H^m$. So it is a base.

A nice (and free) reference for these classical facts is [*Harmonic Function Theory*](http://www.axler.net/HFT.html), by S.Axler,  P.Bourdon, and W.Ramey; see thm 5.25.

Comment: a further question is: what about permutation invariant basis? 

Comment: Thanks this perfectly answers my question. For your "further question", is it possible to find such basis explicitely ?

Comment: I'd like to know it... I've post it as a follow-up of your question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78694/symmetric-basis-of-harmonic-homogeneus-polynomials 