# Is there a nice orthogonal basis of spherical harmonics?

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, spherical-geometry

Recall that a function is *harmonic* if its Laplacian is zero. Let $\mathrm{Harm}(n,k)$ denote the vector space of $n$-variate harmonic polynomials that are homogeneous with degree $k$. When working with spherical harmonics, we endow this vector space with the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ defined in terms of the uniform probability measure over the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Many proofs involving spherical harmonics pass to an implicit orthogonal basis for this inner product space, but for computations, it is sometimes helpful to have an explicit basis.

> **Question.** Is there a "nice" choice of orthogonal basis for $(\mathrm{Harm}(n,k),\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$? In particular, is
> there a choice for which there exists a fast algorithm to compute an
> arbitrary decomposition in the basis (à la FFT)?

Comment: Am I right in understanding that the question is interesting because of the restriction to polynomials? Physicists use explicit non-polynomial orthogonal bases for spherical harmonics to solve the Schrodinger equation in the $1/r$ potential, right?

Answer (score 9):

The book ["Hyperspherical Harmonics and Their Physical Applications"](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/10690) by Avery $\times 2$, has an explicit description using a product of Gegenbauer polynomials in the cosines of the angles of the hyperspherical coordinate system. See Formula 3.65.

Answer (score 5):

A simple basis for  $\mathcal{H}(n,k)$ is described in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78694/symmetric-basis-of-harmonic-homogeneous-polynomials), however, not so symmetric as one may hope at a first glance, as it is shown in the answer.
You may also want to check the beautiful (free online) textbook [Harmonic Function Theory](https://archive.org/details/harmonicfunction00axle_418) by Axley-Bourdon-Ramey.

Comment: The simple basis almost sounds like a solution of Shubin's Conjecture mentioned on page 10 of https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.1174  What am I missing?