Explicit basis of symmetric harmonic polynomials
An orthonormal basis for the space of harmonic polynomials in $n$ variables is provided by the spherical harmonics on the $n-1$ sphere, see e.g. wiki.
From there, constructing an orthonormal basis for the subspace of harmonic polynomials symmetric in $n$ variables is straightforward but laborious (or is it?). Are there known closed expressions, or simple derivation, for such a basis?

Related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78694/symmetric-basis-of-harmonic-homogeneous-polynomials ?

With $n=2$ it seems reasonably simple to derive a basis for the harmonic symmetric polynomials with one polynomial of each degree except 2, and then normalise them with Gram-Schmidt. With $n=3$ it becomes more complicated because there are multiple independent basis polynomials of some degrees.
